# How can I disable logging on my Umbraco sites?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

I am running Umbraco and the Log folder in Umbraco gets huge and is killing me.

For now, I just go in a delete the files regularly, but I would really like to turn off logging.

However, I can not figure out how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

In the Umbraco config folder you will find a file called log4net.config where you can configure your logging. If you want to make it less chatty and just log errors instead of debug and info logs you can change the logging level.

Example:

Change:

```
<priority value="Info"/>
```

to this

```
<priority value="Error"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend turning off logging completely. But still, if you want to do it, open the umbracosettings config file (**/config/umbracosettings.config** - I think) and look for **enableLogging**